# Monitor user activity at Click Once deployment server

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a C# application deployed using Click Once.  How can I retrieve some measures of activity at the Click Once server.  The app checks for updates each time it is restarted.  Relatively small audience--less than 50 users.  Ideally want to develop a user list.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just create a simple web service that gets called when your app starts to log the user activity?

If that's not an option you could use [Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) to query your web server logs for activity.